# How to share plain formatted texts from html in assets folder with intent

Tags: android, html

I was using this code below without noticing that the share intent generates text string directly from html files stored in assets folder. Sharing intents extract raw html code for sharing instead of plain texts the users will understand. It exposes the html content which i don't like.
Please help and tell me what i must have done wrong in this code below. I want to share texts users will understand not html text.

I use Webview to load html files from assets folder.

**This reads my .html file and extract the exact html text inside that file**

```
private String getTextFromAssets(String fileName){
        try {
            final int bufferSize = 1024;
            final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];

            InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);

            final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            int charsRead;
            while((charsRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                out.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
            }
            Log.d("HtmlText", out.toString());
            return out.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("HtmlText", "HTML Read Error: "+e.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**This where i called the method with intent readily for sharing**

```
case R.id.share_button:

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextFromAssets("html_files/newhtml_b1.html"));
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

                //share Copied Text characters via other apps button


        }
```

Comment: If you are sharing HTML, use `text/html` as the MIME type. However, many apps will assume that `EXTRA_TEXT` is plain text, not HTML. You may need to write the HTML out to a file, then use `FileProvider` and `EXTRA_STREAM` instead of `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: Is this correct?    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getTextFromAssets("html_files/newhtml_2.html"));
                sendIntent.setType("text/html");
                Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: No. If you are going to provide the content as a string, you need to use `EXTRA_TEXT`. If you want to use `EXTRA_STREAM`, write your string to a file and use `FileProvider`.

Comment: Sir I appreciate your time. Please give me correction from my code so that I can accept as answer for others to reference from it.

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/PdfProvider) (profiled in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) demonstrates the basic technique of writing content to a file and making it available via `FileProvider`. In my case, I am using `ACTION_VIEW` and a PDF file instead of `ACTION_SEND` and HTML, but the rest is the same.

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/tree/v1.2/T30-Share/ToDo) (profiled in [this other book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore)) uses `ACTION_SEND`, HTML, and `FileProvider`. However, it is a much larger Kotlin app than the Java one from my previous comment.

Comment: I implemented using FileProvider but didn't get it right. I got lost. Please teach me with with improved method

Comment: I thought you  would respond to me

Comment: "I implemented using FileProvider but didn't get it right. I got lost" -- you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question. There, you can provide a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining what "got lost" means.